# How do I move a specific child in CCScrollLayer?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am working to convert my CCScrollLayer.cpp code into more of a CCPicker code. In CCScrollLayer, I've defined a baselayer (CCColorLayer) to hold all of the menu objects. I also have a border that holds the ScrollLayer (using glScissor) called "overlay" that I want to be completely static.

### In Objective C:

```
...
    self.baseLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:(ccColor4B){150,150,150,0} width:s.width height:imgSize.height * numPages];

    for (int i=0; i < [arrayPages count]; i++) {
        CCNode* n = arrayPages[i];
        n.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2 + i * (imgSize.height + padding)); 
        [baselayer addChild:n];
    }

    baseLayer.position = ccp(-s.width/2, -s.height/2 - s.height * currentPage);
    [self addChild:baselayer];
...

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

        CGPoint n = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
        baselayer.position = ccp(touchStartedbaseLayerPosition.x, touchStartedbaseLayerPosition.y + n.y - touchStartedPoint.y);

}
```

### In C++

```
...
        overlay=new CCSprite();
        overlay->initWithFile("overlay.png");
        overlay->setPosition(ccp(300,300));
        overlay->autorelease();

        CCLayerColor* baselayer = new CCLayerColor();
        baselayer->initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255,255));
        baselayer->setOpacity(255);
        baselayer->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(s.width/10, (layers->count()*scrollWidth)));
        baselayer->setPosition(s.width*.41,300);
        baselayer->autorelease();

        // Loop through the array and add the screens
        unsigned int i;
        for (i=0; i<layers->count(); i++)
        {
            CCLayer* l = static_cast<CCLayer*>(layers->objectAtIndex(i));
            l->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0,0));
            l->setPosition(ccp(s.width/40,(i*scrollWidth)));
             baselayer->addChild(l);
        }

        this->addChild(baselayer,1);
        this->addChild(overlay,1);
...

void CCScrollLayer::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *touch, CCEvent *withEvent)
{

    CCPoint touchPoint = touch->getLocation(); // Get the touch position
    touchPoint = this->getParent()->convertToNodeSpace(touchPoint);

    baselayer->setPosition(ccp(0,(-(currentScreen-1)*scrollWidth)+(touchPoint.y-startSwipe)));
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but as soon as I try to start scrolling, I get a fatal error in the touchdispatcher

> ```
>                 case CCTOUCHMOVED:
>                     pHandler->getDelegate()->ccTouchMoved(pTouch, pEvent);
> ```

I'm guessing I'm missing something simple here. Can you point me in the write direction?

Comment: It seems like the problem isn't here. You might register the touch dispatcher but forgot to unregister somewhere, or you forgot to define the ccTouchMoved function in .h file.

Comment: I definitely have ccTouchMoved in my h file. I am registering my touch dispatch onEnter() with CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, false); Is that the correct callout for it to move the baselayer only?

Comment: try to change the last value to true to see what is happening?